# After udgrade lost all drivers. low screen res, no network, no sound card

Tags: drivers, grub2, upgrade, hardware

my PC runs on 21.10.  It did its usual daily update, but today after booting I find that the login screen was low resolution and there was no network and once booted there was no network, low screen resolution and no sound card.  I basically can do little with the PC.  I also noted that whilst the GRUB screen was a normal resolution, the text is not showing and I can not move the cursor, so can not select Advanced - Recovery.  Also noticed when going into GRUB rescue that there is a new entry of each reboot, something script.

The processor is an Intel i5 - 2500K, 32G memory and over 2,700 storage.  Whilst there is a partition for Windows, it is not installed and there are no other OS on the machine.

Do you need anything else?  What cmd should I try?

Thank you.

As I am not allowed to answer my own query, please see the below solution.

SOLVED:  I changed GRUB, via GRUB Customizer to boot into an earlier kernel recovery.  Went through the options, such as enable network, check drives, fix packages etc, and did an update whilst there.  Then rebooted and the network and audio returned.  Then went into additional drivers and changed the video driver to NVIDIA and rebooted.  All seems OK now.  I am guessing that the upgrade was incomplete.

Comment: Hi ! Can you boot into grub recovery please clarify that part out , also open a tty with Ctrl + alt + f5 then post the output of `uname -r`

Comment: Uname -r comes up with 5.13.0-22-generic

Comment: And can boot to grub recovery.   Also grub says Syntex error

Comment: Kernel seems to be ok (But I am not sure) , Do you know what was updated in the last update ? Was the update complete ? Any errors you faced while doing the upgrade ?

Comment: Update went as usual without hitch.  I think I saw a kernel update in there, but don't take much notice.

Comment: What is the result of `sudo update-grub`

Comment: It lists all kernels in the range 5.13.0-20 to 22

Comment: SOLVED:  I changed GRUB, via GRUB Custimizer to boot in to an earlier kernal recovery.  Went through the options, such as enable network, check drives, fix packages etc, and did an update whilst there.  Then rebooted and the network and audio returned.  Then went in to additional drivers and changed the video driver to NVIDIA and rebooted.  All seems OK now.  I am guessing that the upgrade was incomplete.

Comment: @user180042 You ARE allowed to answer your own question (if you have enough reputation accrued... and maybe you don't). Just scroll down to the bottom of this page and look for the "Your Answer" box to enter your solution. Later you can come back and mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: In fact, self-answering is encouraged!  You came up with a good solution, put it in an answer.

Comment: @user180042 BTW... I strongly suggest that users DO NOT use `GRUB Customizer`, as it really makes a mess of things.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question, so had to edit my question.  As for grub customized it is all I have to change the default boot option, as stated I could not (not sure if I can now as not tested) change the boot option in grub menu.

Comment: @user180042 FYI... I added an answer for you that shows an easy way to change the default boot option without the use of GC.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

*SOLVED: I changed GRUB, via GRUB Customizer to boot into an earlier kernel recovery. Went through the options, such as enable network, check drives, fix packages etc, and did an update whilst there. Then rebooted and the network and audio returned. Then went into additional drivers and changed the video driver to NVIDIA and rebooted. All seems OK now. I am guessing that the upgrade was incomplete.*

---

re: *"GRUB Customizer it is all I have to change the default boot option"*

FYI. If you edit /etc/default/grub...

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved    # edit this line
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true # add this line
```

Then `sudo update-grub`, you can change the default OS to boot at the GRUB menu, and it'll remember your choice until you change it again.